# Send Lead updates to Exact Target automatically for use in a Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like for updated records to be available in ExactTarget in near real time.

Specifically to be used in a Journey.

I am happy to do the hard work if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us some things you've already tried?  What does your specific scenario look like?  Include screen shots and/or code if you can.